# Can I call a function in a lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda

I would like to do the following but I don't think this will work:

```
.OrderByDescending(s => Score(s)), ...


private double Score(Story s)
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan elapsed = now.Subtract(s.PostedOn);
            double daysAgo = elapsed.TotalDays;

            return s.Votes.Count + s.Comments.Count - daysAgo;
        }
```

a. should this work?
   b. if not, do I need to query for the stories and then sort them by the score?

Comment: It this LINQ-to-Objects? Or LINQ-to-SQL? EF? It makes a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that should work if the sequence is a sequence of `Story` items; what problem are you having? Note that if `Score` doesn't apply to any instance, it might be worth making it static.

Another option is to make the Score() method an instance method on a `Story`, or an extension method.

Note that this only applies to LINQ-to-Objects; if you are using LINQ-to-SQL / LINQ-to-Entities, etc you either need to use a lambda for the whole thing, or (in LINQ-to-SQL only) use a UDF-mapped function (on the data-context) to calculate the value.

Example (LINQ-to-Objects) with your original syntax:

```
using System.Linq;
using System;
class Story { // declare type
    public DateTime PostedOn { get; set; }
    // simplified purely for convenience
    public int VotesCount { get; set; }
    public int CommentsCount { get; set; }
}
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        // dummy data
        var data = new[] {
            new Story { PostedOn = DateTime.Today,
                VotesCount = 1, CommentsCount = 2},
            new Story { PostedOn = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1),
                VotesCount = 5, CommentsCount = 22},
            new Story { PostedOn = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2),
                VotesCount = 2, CommentsCount = 0}
        };
        var ordered = data.OrderByDescending(s=>Score(s));
        foreach (var row in ordered)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(row.PostedOn);
        }
    }

    private static double Score(Story s) {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan elapsed = now.Subtract(s.PostedOn);
        double daysAgo = elapsed.TotalDays;
        // simplified purely for convenience
        return s.VotesCount + s.CommentsCount - daysAgo;
    }
}
```

Add a `this` (i.e. `Score(this Story s)`), and you can use:

```
.OrderByDescending(s=>s.Score())
```

Answer (score 2):

On a minor note, you may write

```
.OrderByDescending(Score)
```

since "Score"'s signature fulfills the required signature.